# Trying to get wait status to work with file download

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

**Environment: .Net 3.5, jQuery 2.1.4, IE9 support**

Can't seem to get wait status(`spin.gif`) to appear, do a file download with generic handler, and then make wait status disappear. The problem is I'm not getting the dialog to download the file.

**aspx - client**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" /><img src="spin.gif" id="Spin1" style="display: none;" />
        </div>

    </form>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var btn1 = document.getElementById('Button1');
            var spn1 = document.getElementById('Spin1');
            btn1.onclick = function () {
                //alert('achievement unlocked!');

                //window.location = "handler1.ashx";
                $.ajax({
                    beforeSend: function () { spn1.style.display = "inline-block" },
                    url: "handler1.ashx",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (result) {
                        spn1.style.display = "none";
                        //alert('done.')
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ashx - server**

```
public class handler1 : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        //Download the CSV file.
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.csv");
        context.Response.Charset = "";
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        context.Response.Output.Write("Hello, World");
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ajax beforeSend` function code seems correct. What is the issue?

Comment: I'm not getting the prompt to download the file

Comment: above question is regarding to show loading gif image during the ajax process? or prompt to download the file?

Comment: _"The problem is I'm not getting the dialog to download the file."_ Does `window.location = "handler1.ashx;"` not produce expected result? You can alternatively remove `context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.csv");` header, use `Blob`, URL.createObjectURL()`, `<a>` element with `download` attribute to offer file for download.

Comment: Tried that, but then the spin.gif doesn't work properly. I add the line to show the spinner, and then after window.location I add the line to hide it. Well, this results in the spinner never showing.

Comment: The file at Question is only `"Hello, World"`. Why do you expect `<img>` element to be displayed within the span necessary to get file over network?

Comment: If you like to see the loading code is working or not then put `window.location` code inside `setTimeout` function to wait for 2-3 seconds to see it

Comment: There's a thread.sleep of 5 seconds to simulate a long running process on the server

Comment: It also depends upon `spin.gif` image size to load, also make sure you are using  id `Spin1` once in your page, or rather try changing your id and check. otherwise code seems fine

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code looks workable - as I don't have access to the server side of it I replaced in your posted code the ajax and callback for a setTimeout() call. Run the snippet and click the button - spinner image (missing source of course) appears and 2 secs later its gone.

So I guess you are experiencing that the spinner appears but does not go away, so I expect some issue with the ajax. What makes you think it works?

```js
        window.onload = function () {
            var btn1 = document.getElementById('Button1');
            var spn1 = document.getElementById('Spin1');
            btn1.onclick = function () {

                spn1.style.display = "inline-block";
                setTimeout( function(){
                  spn1.style.display = "none";
                  }, 
                  2000
                  )

            }
        }
```

```html
    <form id="form1">
        <div>
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" /><img src="spin.gif" id="Spin1" style="display: none;" />
        </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `"content-disposition", "attachment;` header. Offer file for download at `success` of `$.ajax()` using `<a>` element, `download` attribute, `Blob URL`

```
var a = $("<a>", {download:"SqlExport.csv"}), blob, url;

$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function () { spn1.style.display = "inline-block" },
  url: "handler1.ashx",
  type: "POST",
  success: function (result) {
             spn1.style.display = "none";
             blob = new Blob([result], {type:"text/plain"});
             url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
             a.attr("href", url);     
             $("body").append(a);            
             a[0].click();
             $(window).one("focus", function() {
               URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
               if (blob.close) blob.close();
               a.remove();
             });
           }
});
```

Comment: I have to support IE9 and Blob not supported : ( I apologize for not making that part clear to begin with. I didn't think it would come down to that.

Comment: I've used an iframe before but how would it be used in this case?

Comment: Set `<iframe>` `src` to `"handler1.ashx"`